# Sort by count HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to sort `School`s by the number of `Student`s. There is a `ManyToOne` / `OneToMany` relationship between them.

This is not working but this is what I have so far

`from School s order by count(s.students)`

I would prefer not to use Criteria as I would have to refactor a lot of code. Is there a way to achieve this with `HQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. This worked

`from School s order by size(s.students)`

As per the Hibernate documentation

> You can test the size of a collection with the special property size or the special size() function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work *(expecting that there is relation between `school` and `student` like **`student.School`**)*:

```
//from School s order by count(s.students)
FROM School s 
ORDER BY (
  SELECT count(st) FROM Student st WHERE s.ID = st.School.ID 
)
```

Comment: I tried and now I'm getting this exception `ERROR PARSER:56 - <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query`
I also tried `order by (select count(s.students))` which gives me the same exception